# How to calculate days between two dates using C++ Win32 API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

i am using C++ win32 API...

i have these values.

> pwdlastset date(ex:25-9-2012), current date(ex:1-11-2012),  maxpwdage
>   count(ex 54 days) pwdwarningdays(14 days)...

Now i want to calculate password expiry date...

i have try the below code...

```
if(lastpwdchmon==currentMonth)
                        {
                        lCount=currentDay-lastpwdchday;
                        }
                        else if(lastpwdchmon<currentMonth)
                        {
                            lCount=((currentDay+30)-lastpwdchday);
                        }
```

but,i have a problem...

i mean,just i need to calculate how many days between the currentdate & pwdlastset date?

How to achieve this?

Comment: What type of DATE structure are you using? `SYSTEMTIME`, `DATE`, `FILETIME`?

Comment: @ BigBoss : lastpwdchday is DATE...maxpwdage LONG...but i convert all into integer.

Comment: Convert to ticks. Add appropriate amount of seconds. Turn those ticks into a date. ...? PROFIT!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATE` is `COM` approach to hold date/time. its integral part contain number of days from an epoch(doesn't matter here) and fractional part indicate time of the day. So to compute number of days between 2 `DATE` you can do this:

```
DATE d1 = get_date1(), d2 = get_date2();
int number_of_days = static_cast<int>( d1 - d2 );
```

To get current date as `DATE` you can use:

```
DATE get_now( bool asUTC = false ) {
    SYSTEMTIME stm;
    (asUTC ? ::GetSystemTime : ::GetLocalTime)( &stm );
    DATE res;
    SystemTimeToVariantTime( &stm, &res );
    return res;
}
```

To convert fields of date/time into `DATE` you may use:

```
DATE to_date( int year, WORD month, WORD day,
    WORD h = 0, WORD m = 0, WORD s = 0, WORD ms = 0 )
{
    SYSTEMTIME stm = { year, month, 0, day, h, m, s, ms };
    DATE res;
    if( !SystemTimeToVariantTime(&stm, &res) ) {/* Handle error */}
    return res;
}
```

Comment: `get_date1` & `get_date2` are sample functions, but if you want to get current date, or you have various fields of the date, see my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know what your DATE is, but if you've got them all in time_t then just subtract the two and divide the results by 86400 (60*60*24).